# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter.INSTANCE

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am getting this error in Eclipse.

I know there are many similar questions, but most of them are for Android Studio.
Can anyone answer how this can be solved for Eclipse?

I know that repackaging is one of the ways.
But to be very honest I have no idea on how to do it...

I searched the web, but I had no luck so far...

Comment: hello @Stephen you find solutions ? i have same problem ...

Comment: @JosephMekwan no luck till now trying to upload image using HttpUrlConnection